# Action callback in a custom messagebox

Tags: c#, silverlight, callback

This is the function that is defined in my code

```
    public static void ConfirmMessage(string title, string msg, Action callback)
    {
        DialogWindow dlg = new DialogWindow();
        dlg.Title = title;
        dlg.Message.Content = msg;
        dlg.OKButton.Unloaded += delegate { if (callback != null) { callback(); } };
        dlg.Show();
    }
```

How do I call this function so that it executes a custom function defined in my code? can somebody give an example?

Answer (score 2):

delegate `System.Action` stands for a function with no parameters which doesn't return a value.
So, you would use your method like this:

```
void myFunction()
{
    //your code
}

//then...

ConfirmMessage("Dialog caption", "Dialog text", myFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example:

```
ConfirmMessage("Hello", "World", () => { /* your code here */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

dlg.OKButton.Unloaded += (s1,e1)=> { if (callback != null) { callback(); };